# How to only remove file extensions while keeping other parts as they are

Tags: linux, unix, find

I have quite a few files with different extensions sitting under sub folders like 'aaa'

```
/f1/aaa/a.txt
/f1/aaa/a.sql
/f1/f2/aaa/b.txt
/f1/f2/aaa/b.csv
```

what I need is to extract all these files from /f1 and only remove their extensions:

```
/f1/aaa/a
/f1/f2/aaa/b
```

Comment: find ./ -type f | grep -i aaa | while read fn; do echo ${fn%.*};done

Comment: Are you intending to actually move the files, just display their names, or remove the file extensions from the actual file? In the first or last case, you will end up losing some files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "extract and remove their extensions" you mean renaming them as you go, this would achieve it.

```
find f1 -path "*/aaa/*" -type f -exec bash -c 'mv -i -- "$0" "${0%.*}"' {} \;
```

Or, to merely print the files without their extension:

```
find f1 -path "*/aaa/*" -type f -exec bash -c 'echo "${0%.*}"' {} \;
```

Instead of `grep`ing over `find`'s output, you should use its built-in filtering capabilities to find the matching files. Otherwise, you'd get false positives for files including the string `aaa`.

Filename substitutions [should always be quoted](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) to prevent whitespace or shell glob patterns from being expanded.

Furthermore, [`find` output shouldn't be piped to `while`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) unless you null-delimit the output. If you really just want to "do something" with every file, piping to `while` is not necessary. The same effect can be achieved with the `-exec` option.

If you need `find … | while`, then this is safer (don't forget to quote the filename):

```
find … -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do command "$file"; done
```